# Dynamically add to other form in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vb.net-2010

Is it possible add items to listboxes I have on Form2 with out using

```
If i = 1 Then
Form2.listbox1.items.add(item) 
elseif  i = 2 Then
Form2.listbox2.items.add(item) 
End if
```

I want to achieve something like

```
Form2.listbox(i).items.add(item) '<-- I know this is not the correct way.
```

Please Help

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't expose the controls of Form2 but instead have public methods to manipulate the listbox. Then Form1 can call Form2 methods. Just add your listbox in a list and you could do what you want.

Comment: Form2 has over 150 public listboxes I need to add data into this form to then plot to a chart. I am leaving it in the listboxes in-case I need the data before doing a re-plot.

Comment: Put another way, pass the *data* to the form and let it do what it needs to.  You should also use form instances.

Comment: Are you saying that the list box aren't displayed but are used only to store values?

Comment: Yes the list-boxes only store the values and are not accrual list-boxes they are only "Public y1 As New Listbox"

Comment: Soo... why don't use variables and public properties instead? Use `List(Of String)`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a lot of controls (150 ListBoxes) on a Form, it's always better to create them dynamically at run-time, fill them with items, and then add the ListBox boxes to the Controls on Form2.  First you have to load Form2, (but it doesn't have to be visible yet).

In the code below, you first add the ListBoxes to Form2 (doesn't have to be visible, but does have to be instantiated).  Then set or get all of the ListBox item values by Casting in which the name and type of control is used to change the controls parameters.  The casting "Ctype" command is used when you know the name of a control, and want to access and change a control's parameters when only the controls name is known.

```
Dim myfrm2 As New Form2 'instantiates Form 2 as an object
'myfrm2.Show()  ' Use this if you want to show Form2 on the screen
'next, create 150 ListBox controls and add them to Form2's control
Dim Cnt as Integer = 0
For k = 1 To 6
   For i = 1 to 25
      Cnt += 1
      Dim lbx As New ListBox
      str = "Form2_ListBox_" & Cnt
      lbx.Name = str
      lbx.Left = (k-1) * 80 + 50 
      lbx.Top = 50 + 25 * i
      lbx.Width = 50
      lbx.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
      myfrm2.Controls.Add(lbx)
   Next
Next 
'Assume there are 10 list items per list box
'To set ListBox values in Form 2:
Dim arraylbvalues(150,10) as Object
'fill array above with text or numbers
For i = 1 to 150
   For j = 1 to 10
      CType(myfrm2.Controls("Form2_ListBox_" & i ), ListBox).Items(j) = arraylbvalues(i, j) 
   Next j
Next i

'To get ListBox values in Form 2:
For i = 1 to 150
   For j = 1 to 10
      arraylbvalues(i, j) = CType(myfrm2.Controls("Form2_ListBox_" & i ), ListBox).Items(j)
   Next j
Next i
```

Also, if you don't already have a Form2 created, then modify the first command above to be:

```
Dim myfrm2 as New Form
```